# Opening multiple tabs in specific window of browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I know JavaScript has a method

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

with it I can open a tab or new window with a name 
eg.

```
window.open('www.google.com','name1');
```

And replace the content in same tab by calling

```
window.open('www.yahoo.com','name1');
```

**Question:**
Can I identify I window with set of tab with name? 
Example: open all google related link from my webpage in windowname1 and open all yahoo related links in windowname2

Details:
In my webpage I have four links
www.google.com
www.google.com/psearch

www.yahoo.com
www.yahoo.com/mail

When a user clicks first goolge link -> a new window is opened  with name ='alpha'
when the user clicks second google link -> It does not open a new window but open a new tab in window 'alpha'

When a user clicks first yahoo link -> a new window is opened  with name ='beta'
when the user clicks second yahoo link -> It does not open a window link but open a new tab in window 'beta'

Comment: Well, did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: This works but I am asking If I can Open a new tab in specific existing window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Browsers provide JavaScript on websites no means of managing tabs/windows beyond a single name for a viewport.

Comment: are you saying we can't have a "Window" name but only tab name? (tabname === windowname if  window have only one tab)

Comment: Yes. The object name `window` predates tab support in browsers.

Comment: Yes Got it. the function name window is bit confusing for new generation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can map the urls to the names of their windows:

```
var mapping = {
  'www.google.com' : 'alpha',
  'www.google.com/psearch' : 'alpha',
  'www.yahoo.com' : 'beta',
  'www.yahoo.com/mail' : 'beta'
}
```

That way, you can access the name by url, and use the name to open a window or use an existing window:

```
var name = mapping[url];
window.open(url,name);
```

Comment: How would I open specific new tab in specific new window??

Comment: Does this not replace the content of tab instead of opening new tab in window??

Comment: @Gaurav from JS, you can't decide opening a window or a tab. To JS, windows and tabs are the same. The closest you can get to specifying where to open locations is the name.

Comment: yeah I have tried this ... this only replaces content of existing pages.  I think we do not have any method to identify windows with name. we can only identify tabs with name. Anyway thanks for reply